# document.getElementById("xxx").name = "sample" not working in firefox but works in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mozilla

Can somebody help on this one. I am trying to set the name of a element dynamically.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Have you looked in a DOM inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute).

Example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("xxx");
element.setAttribute("name", "sample");
```

Comment: It's borked in IE < 8 and best avoided.

Comment: Really? Never realized that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5ve4g/

to check run the following script

```
document.getElementById('xxx').name = 'some-name';
var el = document.getElementById('xxx');
alert(el.name);
```

If you are using firebug to check it, then know that if the element does not officially has a `name` attribute then it will not show in the DOM.

But the element does have that property now..